# Printing Data inside a div

Tags: printing, printing-web-page

I have a lot of DIVs having some data in my web page & I want to print a data of a specific div by using "window.print()" without opening any popup. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use CSS Media Types like this:

```
    @media print {
        #printable {
            display:block;
            overflow: visible;
        }

        #nonprintable {
            display:none;
        }
    }
    @media screen {
        body, table, tr, td { font:12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
        .divStyles {
            width:850px;
            height:150px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            background-color: #ccc;
            padding: 15px;
        }
    }
```

I have created an example for you, see a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/Vuw6D/3/

Comment: @Oded: Mr. I Think you didn't understand the question. First read it then vote in negative.