# How to print a div with style support?

Tags: javascript, css

I want print div content with style(separate .css file).
I tried much but unable to print with style support.

Please help me!

Comment: See this post: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454046/printing-data-inside-a-div/6454089#comment-7579488

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a function on clicking of "PRINT" button. and the function contain the div you want to print.Here in my example i want to print the content of div with id  "main"

```
function CallPrint() { 
  var prtContent = document.getElementById('main'); 
  var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'width=800,height=650,scrollbars=1,menuBar=1'); 

  var str = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head><style type=\"text/css\">.margin_0px table{*float:left} <\/style> <title>PRINT</title> <script type=\"text/javascript\">function abc() {} <link href=\"/css/internal111.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\"/></head><body  onload="abc();"><div class=\"maintable_big\">' + prtContent.innerHTML</div></div></body></html>';  
  WinPrint.document.write(str); 
  WinPrint.document.close(); 
  WinPrint.focus(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [@media print](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) in your css file, I'd say. Here's a [comprehensive article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) on the subject.

Comment: should work, only not well supported in older browsers, according to http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/at-media

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're after?

```
<link href="stylesheetFileForPrintingOnly.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print">
```

You can read more about the media attribute here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/link

and here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/link/media